# Accessing the index of a tuple nested inside a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, indexing, nested, tuples

I'm trying my hand at a text-based chess game and am currently working on a system I can use to calculate positions on the board. Here's a snippet of the approach I'm currently taking:

```
_file = ('A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H')

A1 = {'File' : _file[0], 'Rank' : _rank[0],
'Color' : color['Dark'], 'Piece' : pieces['None']},
```

The dictionary A1 describes a square on the chessboard and has parameters for the file and rank of the square, its color, and what piece is on it. All of the values currently refer to tuples similar to _file. The pieces use the same system to describe where and what they are.

I'd like to be able to write some piece of code to change the tuple index of a value inside my dictionary so that it looks like this:

```
 A1 = {'File' : _file[1], 'Rank' : _rank[0],
'Color' : color['Dark'], 'Piece' : pieces['None']},
```

But everything I've tried so far operates on the index of the string 'A' referenced by _file[0]. For example,

```
print (A1['File'][1])
```

Gives us an error that the index is out of range because we're really telling it this:

```
print (_file[0][1]) # which means this:
print 'A'[1]
```

And of course a one-letter string doesn't have an index at [1].

I may end up scrapping this approach and using integers instead of tuples for the sake of simplicity, but if I can get this working it'll be easier to read (I think.) Is there any way to operate on a the index of a nested tuple?

Comment: Why `A1 = {'File' : _file[0], 'Rank' : _rank[0],
'Color' : color['Dark'], 'Piece' : pieces['None']}` has `'File' : _file[0] ` not `'File' : _file`

Comment: Because its file should be A, which is at _file[0]

Comment: Yes there is the way but you don't have nested tuples.

Comment: You don't have a tuple nested in the dictionary. Accessing a tuple element by index gives you the element, not the tuple. It doesn't keep the index with it somehow, that doesn't make sense.

Comment: I don't follow. The tuple _file is nested in the dictionary A1.

Comment: Ahh. I see what you're saying. The problem is, I need that specific tuple element, but I need to be able to change what element is being referred to.

Comment: Do you want File to be pointing to sometimes `A` or `B` or `C`?

Comment: Exactly. Sometimes it needs to point to another letter

Comment: Assuming that the 'File' item will _always_ reference `_file`, etc, I'd just store the indices & keys in the dict, like this: `A1 = {'File' : 0, 'Rank' : 0, 'Color' : 'Dark', 'Piece' : 'None'}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the value of `File` in the dictionary you need to re-assign it with the new index, for example:

```
_file = ('A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H')
A1 = {'File' : _file[0], 'Rank' : _rank[0],
'Color' : color['Dark'], 'Piece' : pieces['None']},
# _file[0] will be replaced with 'A' in the above dicitonary

A1['File'] = _file[1]

# now it will be 'B' instead
```

Comment: That works to change the value attached to 'File', but in the long run I need some way to check, add, and subtract from that index. For example, if I had a rook was on A1 and wanted to move it three squares to the right, I'd need to add 3 to its _file index. Or if I wanted to move a piece to some arbitrary square, I'd need to check the rank and file of the target square to make sure a friendly piece wasn't already there first. If there's not an easy way to grab that index, I may need to scrap this and try a different approach.

Comment: If that is the case, you can store the index only instead. Like `A1 = {'File': 0}` then to print the position: `print _file[A1['File']]`

Comment: @John You are not storing the index so there's no index to check or change.

Comment: Having played with it a little, I think this is going to be the best route. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The dictionary contains reference to a slot in the _file object.
When you call `A1['File']` it actually points to `_file[0]` object. You get this object back, and not the tuple it in it as you expect.

You can update index value of the tuple inside the dict:
`A1['File'] = _file[1]` and then when you call `A1['File']` you would get `_file[1]`. You need to keep the index of the tuple as part of the A dict, and whenever the index is updated you update the tuple index as well.

```
_file = ('A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H')
A1 = {'File' : _file[0], 'idx': 0}

def move_up(d):
    d['idx'] += 1
    d['File'] = _file[d['idx']]
```

Output

```
>>> A1
{'idx': 0, 'File': 'A'}
>>> move_up(A1)
>>> A1
{'idx': 1, 'File': 'B'}
```

Comment: This might work! I'll play around with it and will let you know how it goes.

Comment: You could condense the 3 first lines of `move_up` into a single `d ['idx'] += 1` statement...

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I edited the answer, this looks more elegant. Thanks